# Conversion of word to pdf with original document dimensions using spire doc

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, pdf, spire.doc

How to convert word file to a PDF, so that the page setup like margins and orientations of source documents and output PDF want to same.I tried the following code from [E-ICEBLUE](http://www.e-iceblue.com/Knowledgebase/Spire.Doc/Program-Guide/How-to-Convert-Word-to-PDF.html#page).

```
'Load Document
Dim document As New Document()
document.LoadFromFile("E:\work\documents\TestSample.docx")

'Convert Word to PDF
document.SaveToFile("toPDF.PDF", FileFormat.PDF)

'Launch Document
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("toPDF.PDF")
```

But the converted PDF don't have the full document.Its header and footer is not showing and right side of the document is cutting. How to solve this ? [This is my converted pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32u9c.png)

Comment: Have u looked at the COM Interop?

Answer (score 0):

Here demo with code.

Try your doc file and generate pdf. look code

http://www.e-iceblue.com/LiveDemo/Spire.Doc/Conversion.html

With Header and footer

http://www.e-iceblue.com/LiveDemo/Spire.Doc/Header-and-Footer.html